# Loading tor browser gets stuck at establishing encrypted directory connection

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help, censorship

```
19-Feb-17 22:09:06 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
19-Feb-17 22:09:06 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
19-Feb-17 22:09:06 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
19-Feb-17 22:09:06 PM.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
19-Feb-17 22:09:07 PM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
19-Feb-17 22:09:07 PM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
19-Feb-17 22:09:26 PM.000 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 9695DFC35FFEB861329B9F1AB04C46397020CE31 at 128.31.0.39:9101) 
19-Feb-17 22:09:26 PM.000 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
19-Feb-17 22:09:26 PM.000 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
19-Feb-17 22:09:30 PM.200 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
19-Feb-17 22:09:30 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
19-Feb-17 22:09:30 PM.200 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
19-Feb-17 22:09:30 PM.200 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Here is my Log. I don't know what is wrong. Can someone help?

Comment: Possibly censorship. Try using the pluggable transport options, either fetch some obfs4 bridges from https://bridges.torproject.org/ or try the meek bridges.

Answer (score 2):

You have a SSL/TLS active attacker on your connection, use Meek pluggable transport to mitigate this. You can also try obfs4